# Flex or Actionscript Accessing content from a external Illustrator SWF

Tags: actionscript, flash, adobe-illustrator

I have problem accessing content from an Illustrator SWF(I create the swf using illustrator, I export I Save layers as symbols).
When I create my swf file using flash i can access shapes and symbols using this code.

I am trying to get and change the color of a symbols in my swf file

```
var flashMovie:Sprite = this.content as Sprite;
for (var i:int = 0; i < flashMovie.numChildren; i++) 
{                           
flashMovie.getChildAt(i).name;
flashMovie.getChildAt(i).transform.colorTransform.color;                    

}
```

But when I create my swf file using Illustrator it return nothing.

How can can i access the content and change the color of an Illustrator SWF

Comment: By "Illustrator SWF" Do you mean that you used some "Export as SWF" option in Adobe Illustrator?  Or do you mean something else?  It doesn't look like this question has any Flex specific content, so I'm gong to remove the Flex tag and add the Flash tag.

Comment: Yes I am exporting as swf with Illustrator.  I am us Flex 4.5 to create the program, and flash to create the graphics.(The program would allow user the change the colors in a graphic of an external loaded swf file.) If i create the graphic using flash it work fine but when i use illustrator i have a hard time detecting the symbols. is this even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to export AVM2 (AS 3) swf's using Illustrator? Correct me if i am wrong, but as far as I know Illustrator CS5 still exports AVM1 (AS 1 & 2) swf's. Within a AS3 Project all loaded AS2 Movies are represented by the flash.display.AVM1Movie class. This class has no display-chain children, it is just a DisplayObject showing the rendered AVM1 Clip. From this it follows that you can't access any symbols defined by Illustrator.

I am not quite sure if you can use the call() Method to invoke some Method within a AVM1Movie. Is it possible to add AS2 methods within Illustrator? Probably not...

You can either export every element as single swf, or choose some other export format such as svg.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.AVM1Movie;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.describeType;

    public class AIImportDemo extends Sprite
    {
        private var __loader:Loader = new Loader();
        public function AIImportDemo()
        {
            super();
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE
            __loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,__onComplete);
            __loader.load(new URLRequest('assets/myAIExport.swf'));
        }
        private function __onComplete($e:Event):void{
            addChild(__loader);
            trace(describeType(__loader.content));
            trace("is MovieClip "+ (__loader.content is MovieClip)); // false   
            trace("is Sprite "+ (__loader.content is Sprite)); // false
            trace("is Shape "+ (__loader.content is Shape)); // false
            trace("is AVM1Movie "+ (__loader.content is AVM1Movie)); // true
            trace("is Display Object "+(__loader.content is DisplayObject)); // true

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to Copy/Paste your objects from Illustrator to Flash CS. That way vector objects may be ported over as AS3 Shape objects. You can also split them to different Symbols etc...